# PHP Xpath- Select element out of another element

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have problem with Xpath function in PHP. I have created simpleXML than ran xpath to it. Then I wanted to run it to the result of the xpath but only apply it to first element. But it still taking all elements like there was no xpath used. I also printed how the array looked after first xpath and it took exacly what I wanted. Can anyone help, please?

```
$elem = simplexml_load_file($fileIn);

$xpathArg = "//".$arg['eFR'];
$prem = $elem->xpath($xpathArg);

$xpathArg2 = "//".$arg['eSE'];
print_r($prem[0]->xpath($xpathArg2));
```

Comment: please post a valid mini snippet of the XML in question. And what you want it to be. And what you got instead. And content of $arg[] - a complete, self-containing code example. Professional question = professional answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foreach loop with xPath on SimpleXML object returning duplicate data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652575/foreach-loop-with-xpath-on-simplexml-object-returning-duplicate-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XPath starting with `/` is an absolute path. You want a path starting from the context node, otherwise the context node is ignored. Simply prepending a `.` at the beginning of your second xpath query will ensure it starts from the node you specify.

```
$elem = simplexml_load_file($fileIn);

$xpathArg = "//".$arg['eFR'];
$prem = $elem->xpath($xpathArg);

$xpathArg2 = ".//".$arg['eSE'];
print_r($prem[0]->xpath($xpathArg2));
```